# Difference forms using same model in same action

Tags: php, forms, post, yii2

My profile page have 3 forms:

- Avatar form
- User form
- User Metadata form
  Now, I have this working great with 2 and 3 in my controller (2 different models), but I dont know how I can manage when I send the avatar form (only updates avatar) or the user form (only updates email)

There are any way to control whats form is sent and then update the desired propertie or our model? So I can change the email sending a form, or change avatar (of the same model) sending other form.

This my actually working action:

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model = Yii::$app->user->identity;
        $userMeta = PgcUsersMeta::findOne(['fk_user' => $model->id]);

        //Si queremos cambiar el email
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->update(true, ["email"])
        || ($userMeta->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $userMeta->update())) {
            Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('profile-Msg-OK', Yii::t("app","Generic_Changes_OK"));
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        } else {
            return $this->render('index', [
                'model' => $model,
                'userMeta' => $userMeta,
            ]);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please show the related model, view and controller.. I don't understand.. how could be your code ..

Comment: Why not to call `$model->update()` without explicit `$model->update(true, ["email"])` ?

Comment: Because these form is formed only by email field, so I only update the email field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if user uploading an avatar by checking `UploadedFile` instance. Here is an example (assuming your model's attribute name is *avatar*)

```
$model->avatar = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'avatar');
if ($model->avatar) {
    // do stuff
}
```

As another option consider separating this three forms into three different controller's actions e.g. *profile/update-avatar*, *profile/update-email*, *profile/update-meta*. So for uploading avatar your form action would be like `<form action="profile/update-avatar">` and so on